# Catenate on numircs

Tags: solr

I turned off splitOnNumrics and splitOnCaseChange in WDFF because I don't want 123ABC to match documents containing `123` *and* documents with `abc`. Still I want query "123 abc" to match documents containing `123ABC`.

I want to following to be posible:

123 abc -> `123abc`

Wi-Fi -> `wifi`

product 12 -> `product 12mm`

Current settings are:

```
    <fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="title" omitNorms="false" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([mM]\d+)x?([\w]*)" replacement="$1 $2"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="," replace="all" replacement="."/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
    <filter catenateAll="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateWords="1" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="0" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" types="wdfftypes.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>   
    <filter class="solr.DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory" dictionary="compounds_nl.txt" maxSubwordSize="32" minSubwordSize="3" minWordSize="7"/> 
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Kp" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([mM]\d+)x?([\w]*)" replacement="$1 $2"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="," replace="all" replacement="."/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>        
    <filter catenateAll="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateWords="1" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="0" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" types="wdfftypes.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>   
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Kp" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>   
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="prefix_match" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory" maxGramSize="50" minGramSize="2"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter catenateAll="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateWords="1" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="0" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" types="wdfftypes.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter catenateAll="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateWords="1" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="0" generateWordParts="0" preserveOriginal="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" types="wdfftypes.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Basically I want to catenate words and numbers, any ideas how to accomplish this?

I know a website where they can match product "productname 12mm" with `productname12mm` , `productname 12mm`,`productname 12` and `productname12`. This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: have you tried keeping the splits on for indexing and off for query?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and see how many results I get on queries. I will comment my findings.

Comment: This solution works fine.